# Reading document lines to the user (python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program to read 5 lines of a text document to the user, but I can't manage to get it to work. It currently prints line 4 and line 5 along with the "\n" (new line) by each of them. This is the code:

```
filename = 'text_file_example.txt'
myfile = open(filename,'r')
myfile.readlines(5)
print(myfile.readlines(5))
myfile.close()
```

Would it be better to read one line in a for(range 5) loop?

Comment: Did you mean to skip 5 lines first? And could you include an example of the output?

Comment: Also, is this Python 3? You are using `print()` as a function, so I suspect you are but would like a confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The builtin function you are using, `readlines()` does the following ([from the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)):

> `f.readlines()` returns a list containing all the lines of data in the
>   file. If given an optional parameter `sizehint`, it reads that many
>   bytes from the file and enough more to complete a line, and returns
>   the lines from that.

Perhaps you might want to do that:

```
filename = 'text_file_example.txt'
myfile = open(filename,'r')
file_lines = myfile.readlines()
for line in file_lines[:5]: 
    print(line)
myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` returns a list of **all** lines,so you should probably do:

```
lines=myfile.readlines()[:5]
```

But as it loads all lines it is not memory efficient.

So, a better solution here will be to use `itertools.islice`:

```
list(islice(myfile,5)) # it'll return a list of first five lines,
                       # no need of reading all lines
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

```
If given an optional parameter sizehint, 
it reads that many bytes from the file and 
enough more to complete a line, and returns the lines from that
```

so your best option is to use a for loop:

```
for line in myfile.readlines()[:5]:
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the number of lines read, use the file object as an iterable, then *slice* the lines using `itertools.islice`:

```
import itertools

filename = 'text_file_example.txt'
with open(filename,'r') as myfile:
    # skip five
    list(itertools.islice(myfile, 5))
    print(*itertools.islice(myfile, 5), sep='', end='')  # print 5, use newlines from file
```

Note that we pass the 5 read lines to the `print()` function as a series of arguments, not as one object, using the `*` syntax, then disable the automatic space and newline characters; the lines do not need to be separated by spaces and already include newlines.

The above code will only *ever* read 10 lines of your file, regardless of how large it is. Calling `.readlines()` will (try to) read the whole file into memory, regardless of size and available memory.