# getting data out of a txt file

Tags: python

I'm only just beginning my journey into Python. I want to build a little program that will calculate shim sizes for when I do the valve clearances on my motorbike. I will have a file that will have the target clearances, and I will query the user to enter the current shim sizes, and the current clearances. The program will then spit out the target shim size. Looks simple enough, I have built a spread-sheet that does it, but I want to learn python, and this seems like a simple enough project...

Anyway, so far I have this:

```
def print_target_exhaust(f):
    print f.read()

#current_file = open("clearances.txt")
print print_target_exhaust(open("clearances.txt"))
```

Now, I've got it reading the whole file, but how do I make it ONLY get the value on, for example, line 4. I've tried `print f.readline(4)` in the function, but that seems to just spit out the first four characters... What am I doing wrong?

I'm brand new, please be easy on me!
-d

Comment: related mistake here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988421/reading-document-lines-to-the-user-python/13988466#13988466

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read all the lines:

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

Then, to print line 4:

```
print lines[4]
```

Note that indices in python start at 0 so that is actually the fifth line in the file.

Comment: Gotcha, i will try that. Presumably to just take the value in that line and NOT ptint it I would do something like `value = lines[4]` ?
Does it have to be the square bracket?

Comment: +1. But since `readlines` is sort-of-deprecated in 3.3, it may be worth learning the "modern" version, `list(f)` instead of `f.readlines()`. However, that does require understanding a bit more of the basics…

Comment: Correct and yes, you need the square bracket.  Note that the lines returned from `readline` (or `readlines`) will include the newline character so you may want to use `value = lines[4].strip()`.

Comment: Ok, here's what I've got:
`f = open("clearances.txt", "r")`

`exhaust_target = f.readlines()[1]`

`intake_target = f.readlines()[4]`


`print exhaust_target`

`print intake_target`

`f.close`

but then I get an error that says
 "intake_target = f.readlines()[4]
IndexError: list index out of range

What does this mean?

Comment: @Demonic: You can't do newlines in comments. If you need further help, you can either edit your question, or ask a new one, whichever seems more appropriate. But you definitely do not want to keep calling `f.readlines()` over and over. Store the result in a variable: `lines = f.readlines()`. Then you can do `lines[1]`, `lines[4]`, etc. (The reason you're getting an error is that the second time, you're trying to read all the lines that are left, after already having read all the lines… which means you get an empty list of lines, so `[4]` fails.)

Comment: Ooh! That worked great! I've got a lot to learn. Thanks for being so patient with me. I'm sure you'll get sick of me eventually, but unfortunately I learn best by making mistakes and asking questions. Works for me, but I fear it annoys everyone else...

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('myfile') as myfile: # Use a with statement so you don't have to remember to close the file
    for line_number, data in enumerate(myfile): # Use enumerate to get line numbers starting with 0
        if line_number == 3:
            print(data)
            break # stop looping when you've found the line you want
```

More information:

- [with statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)
- [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: This is a good solution as it will not (try to) load all the lines into the memory first.

Comment: @poke: Unless, of course, he wants to look at the 4th line, then the 176th, then the 1st, then the 73rd…

Comment: @abarnert Yeah, for that problem there is no good solution, so I guess this is not a good solution for that problem.

Comment: @kojiro: Sure there is: read the whole thing in at once. (If that takes too much memory, the solution is probably `anydbm`.) And from the comments, it sounds like that _is_ the OP's problem—he wants to read the 4th line, and the 1st line…

Comment: @abarnert meh. You and I disagree about the definition of *good* in this case.

Comment: @kojiro: If you want to randomly access a bunch of lines, you have to split the file into lines. Whether you do that by reading the lines into memory, or reading them into an `anydbm` or other database, there's no way around that.

Comment: @abarnert *there's no way around that* is exactly why I said there's no good solution.

Comment: @kojiro: That just means it's a problem to be solved, not that there is no good solution to the problem. That's why we have programmers. If you have data in a text file, and you want to access it randomly by lines, you split it into lines, and decide how to store it, and there are many good ways to do that, all of which count as good solutions to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Not very efficient, but it should show you how it works. Basically it will keep a running counter on every line it reads. If the line is '4' then it will print it out.

```
## Open the file with read only permit
f = open("clearances.txt", "r")
counter = 0
## Read the first line 
line = f.readline()

## If the file is not empty keep reading line one at a time
## till the file is empty
while line:
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter == 4
        print line
    line = f.readline()
f.close()
```

Comment: In Python there is almost never a good reason to use a manual counter. Use the builtin [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

Comment: Oh man, a counter is one of the few things I know how to use!

Comment: Me too, I am a firmware guy so Python isn't exactly my "thing", but I thought it might be useful to someone.

Comment: @Demonic: `enumerate` is much harder to get wrong (avoids those trivial off-by-one errors that always take hours to debug and then you feel like an idiot), and it immediately signals readers what you're doing. Read [http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/](PEP 279) for further rationale (although much of it is probably lower-level than you're interested in).

Comment: @Demonic A lot of Python's strength shows in the convenience it lends to iteration. Most of the time `enumerate` is just less work. By being less work, it reduces error risk. (For example, you may miss a `counter = counter + 1` in a conditional, but `enumerate` eliminates that possibility.) If you want more, ask about `enumerate` versus manual counters in a separate SO question.

Comment: Ok, excellent. Apologies, I'm still learning how to use the site. My brain is getting full of new things...